# Spring Batch - FlatFileItemWriter is creating folders when it doesnt exist. How to stop this?

Tags: spring-batch

FlatFileItemWriter is creating the output folder when it does not exist, but I want it not to create the folder and throw an error instead. Can anybody please suggest how can I achieve this? 
For example - I don't want the below temp folder to get created when it doesn't exist --

```html
 

<bean id="sampleWriter" class="com.test.writer.SampleWriter"
      scope="step">
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true"/>
    <property name="resource"
              value="file://C:/temp/SAMPLE.txt"/>
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value=","/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch's `FlatFileItemWriter` doesn't have the ability to do that.  That being said, we would welcome a pull request to add it if you wanted.  You can read more about contributing to Spring Batch here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md